# Wikitude cordova build fails

Tags: cordova, wikitude

I followed exactly the tutorial here: http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/phonegap

but when i run cordova build i get this error. Seems like there is a problem with the access rights, but this seems OK for me in the Code...

Any help much appreciated!

```
wikitude/phonegap/WikitudePlugin.java:263: error: cannot find symbol
                        if ( !cordova.hasPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ) {
                                     ^
  symbol:   method hasPermission(String)
  location: variable cordova of type CordovaInterface
/Users/patrick/AugmentedRealityProject/platforms/android/src/com/wikitude/phonegap/WikitudePlugin.java:265: error: cannot find symbol
                            WikitudePlugin.this.cordova.requestPermission(WikitudePlugin.this, WRITE_TO_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                                                       ^
  symbol:   method requestPermission(WikitudePlugin,int,String)
  location: variable cordova of type CordovaInterface
/Users/patrick/AugmentedRealityProject/platforms/android/src/com/wikitude/phonegap/WikitudePlugin.java:462: error: cannot find symbol
            boolean cameraPermissionRequestRequired = !cordova.hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                                                              ^
  symbol:   method hasPermission(String)
  location: variable cordova of type CordovaInterface
/Users/patrick/AugmentedRealityProject/platforms/android/src/com/wikitude/phonegap/WikitudePlugin.java:463: error: cannot find symbol
            _locationPermissionRequestRequired = !cordova.hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && !cordova.hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                                                         ^
  symbol:   method hasPermission(String)
  location: variable cordova of type CordovaInterface
/Users/patrick/AugmentedRealityProject/platforms/android/src/com/wikitude/phonegap/WikitudePlugin.java:463: error: cannot find symbol
            _locationPermissionRequestRequired = !cordova.hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && !cordova.hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                                                                                                                             ^
  symbol:   method hasPermission(String)
  location: variable cordova of type CordovaInterface
/Users/patrick/AugmentedRealityProject/platforms/android/src/com/wikitude/phonegap/WikitudePlugin.java:468: error: cannot find symbol
                this.cordova.requestPermissions(this, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION });
                            ^
  symbol:   method requestPermissions(WikitudePlugin,int,String[])
  location: variable cordova of type CordovaInterface
/Users/patrick/AugmentedRealityProject/platforms/android/src/com/wikitude/phonegap/WikitudePlugin.java:470: error: cannot find symbol
                this.cordova.requestPermission(this, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                            ^
  symbol:   method requestPermission(WikitudePlugin,int,String)
  location: variable cordova of type CordovaInterface
/Users/patrick/AugmentedRealityProject/platforms/android/src/com/wikitude/phonegap/WikitudePlugin.java:473: error: cannot find symbol
                this.cordova.requestPermissions(this, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION });
                            ^
  symbol:   method requestPermissions(WikitudePlugin,int,String[])
  location: variable cordova of type CordovaInterface
/Users/patrick/AugmentedRealityProject/platforms/android/src/com/wikitude/phonegap/WikitudePlugin.java:993: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
9 errors
:compileDebugJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer [here](https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-cordova-plugin/issues/105#issuecomment-174728414)

> make sure that your cordova/phonegap command for android is either cordova platform add android@5.0.0 or cordova build android@5.0.0. Our example app generation script contains the version specifier which ensures that all required runtime permissions functions and constants are available. Might be that you need to update your cordova/phonegap installation.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your Android SDK version is too old. Please Install the Android SDK API level 23 and NDK r10e.